# PowerShell script path from module

Tags: powershell

I have this myModule.psm1 in modules directory:

```
function my-test{
    $global:PSCommandPath>C:\test.txt;C:\test.txt
}
```

and this myScript.ps1

```
my-test
```

When I run myScript.ps1 with PowerShell ISE, I got path of myScript.ps1 in test.txt file, as i expect.

When I run myScript.ps1 with PowerShell, I got empty test.txt file.

How can I fix it?

Comment: .ps* files are associated with a text editor, not a process (.exe) tool. You cannot double-click the file and have it run. To do this, call the .ps* file from a batch file, or convert to exe using the PS2EXE tool from the MS powershellgallery.com or you manually change the file association in file explorer ti point to powershell.exe. Don't do the last option, it's not recommended!!! To use a modules (.psm1) function, that is not autoloaded, you must load it first using the Import-Module cmdlet for .ps1 you should dot source it. See the help files or the web  on running functions from a script.

Comment: Of course my .psm1 module is located in modules directory. I ask about another trouble. function my-test can see variable $global:PSCommandPath when i run script with PowerShell ISE, but cant see when i run with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is PowerShell level 100 stuff.

[If this is really a module, .psm1 file](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20using%20module%20function), then it should be in your modules directory (or directly called from a directory path) and be properly named, then loaded into memory using...

```
Import-Module -Name 'YourModuleName'
```

If you are trying to use a function from a .ps1 file, it too must be loaded, by a direct run of the script or [dot-sourcing it](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=dot%20source%20powershell%20script).

```
. .\my-test.ps1
```

At this point, you call any of the functions in the .ps* loaded resource. Your function name and module name should be different things to avoid confusion.

See the help files, web articles, Youtube videos regarding loading .ps* file and running functions from .ps* files. I've provided the link above to Youtube.

Comment: my .psm1 module is located in modules directory, i dont need to load it manually. When i right click on myscript.ps1 and open with PowerShell ISE, i got path of myscript.ps1 in test.txt, as i expect, its correct. But when i right click on myscript.ps1 and open with PowerShell i got emptiness in test.txt.